# Division in MDX measure

Tags: sql, ssas, mdx

I need to divide a measure for a conversion in an SSAS cube. I have no problem multiplying measures, but the multiplied conversions do not have filters.

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[AEA - NGL BBLs]
AS ([Measures].[Quantity], [Account].[Account].[606000]/42)
+ ([Measures].[Quantity], [Account].[Account].[606010]/42),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me. It's:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[AEA - NGL BBLs]
AS ([Measures].[Quantity], [Account].[Account].[606000])/42
+ ([Measures].[Quantity], [Account].[Account].[606010])/42,
```

Comment: I just tested similar syntax on one of my cubes and got correct numbers back when summing two quotients like you did in the example...when you the multiplied conversions do not have filters, can you elaborate?